# Cloudwatch default metrics EC2 DiskReadOps and DiskWriteOps not reporting

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloudwatch

AWS EC2 instances by default include DiskReadOps and DiskWriteOps metric for attached EBS volumes. I have checked multiple running EC2 Instances running both Windows and Linux and they all display no value data other then 0.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ec2-metricscollected.html

Any idea what the issue may be?

Answer (score 6):

EC2 Instance DiskReadOps and DiskWriteOps Metric are applicable to Instance Store Volumes Only. They do not refer to EBS volumes that are attached to instance.

If you go to Cloudwatch Metrics EBS section you can identify the volume-name attached to the instance and look for VolumeReadOps and VolumeWriteOps metric.

This was an oversight on my part when first asking this question.